# Is "misreact" a word?

Tags: vocabulary, is-it-a-word

I am trying to describe someone's reactions in a situation.  At first I used the word overreact, but then I realized it is not only the person's overreaction but also other kinds of inappropriate or unexpected reactions.  Then I came across "misreact" which seems to be the right word, except that I am not sure if it is a real word.

Comment: Can you give any reason why it *wouldn't* be a legitimate application of the prefix "mis-" to the verb "react"?

Comment: Reactions can be exaggerated or even inappropriate, but can they really be said to be *wrong* per se in the sense the prefix *mis-* would suggest?

Comment: @Lawrence - How about steering left into the front of the oncoming cement truck rather than right to avoid it?

Comment: @HotLicks Assuming it was caused by a lifetime of driving on the left side of the road, I can see where you're coming from. Still, the impulse itself would just be a reaction; it might be labeled an *unfortunate* reaction. Compare: behave/misbehave, align/misalign - there's a sense that something is wrong or even just incorrect. But an almost instinctual impulse - it just *is*, isn't it? One can describe the aftermath as good or bad, happy or sad, etc, but it doesn't seem appropriate to describe the reaction itself that way.

Comment: @Lawrence - I don't understand what you think is the difference between a "misreaction" and an "inappropriate reaction", in an extreme case.

Comment: In any event, it's legitimately constructed.

Comment: @HotLicks you are right!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you can use word *misreact*.

You won't find it in standard dictionaries like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misreact)  or [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?filter=dictionary&query=misreact).
But you can certainly use it to convey the meaning "react in the wrong way".

The prefix *mis-* conveys that something is wrong. From the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mis-):

> *mis-* (prefix)
>   1.  (added to verbs and their derivatives) wrongly. *misapply*
>   1.1 Badly. *mismanage*
>   1.2. Unsuitably. *misname*

A few references for *misreact*:

1. [*Ernest Hemingway's The Sun Also Rises: A Casebook*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=lzzRCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=%22misreact%22&source=bl&ots=hLrlITCqt5&sig=NDQPbGrcfg3XszwQPWvZ6piVnHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvvaSLjOncAhVGTn0KHTrEDSoQ6AEwCHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22misreact%22&f=false), by Linda Wagner-Martin, ed.

   [image]
2. [*The Paranoia Switch: How Terror Rewires Our Brains and Reshapes Our Behavior*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FU_aKyTB08kC&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=%22misreact%22&source=bl&ots=AzTGxy7h8H&sig=DKgzWjBXp7pKGqgxiwAR95xjVnI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvvaSLjOncAhVGTn0KHTrEDSoQ6AEwCXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22misreact%22&f=false) by Martha Stout.

   [image]

Comment: Those dictionaries do not contain every word. Also, your answer is confusing: you call it (a) word then you say it is not. Then you give examples of it. So is it a word that you have found in those examples or what?

Comment: @Knotell No, I haven't said that it is a word, I have explicitly stated it on the top. I said: **"you can use word misreact."** because of prefix **mis-***. You can add this prefix to word "react". Secondly, yes, every word is not defined in those 2 dictionaries, but at the same time, words can be formed for usage.

Comment: It is an example of [combining form](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combining%20form)

Comment: Your answer currently says: (1) "You are correct, you can use word misreact", which means you are calling it a word; (2) "But misreact by itself is not a word." This is stating opposite things. I have no idea what your comment means; you should think how to write what you mean in a more clear manner.

Comment: @Knotell because it is not found in the standard dictionaries. That's the reason, I said it is not a word in itself.

Comment: @Knotell to avoid further confusion, I will remove that line :) Please consider my answer again!

Comment: That's much better!

Comment: An excellent answer. I like the confidence to state the real linguistic situation despite an absence of dictionary support. Up-voted.

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for a word with an actual dictionary definition (although I'm not certain that *misreact* is inappropriate), the closest in form and meaning I can think of is [**miscue**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miscue):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to make a miscue
>
> noun
>
> 2 : MISTAKE, SLIP
>
> the slightest *miscue* could make the trapeze artist lose his grip and fall to the mat below